# esc_html__() and __() not working within arrays

Tags: plugin-development, translation

I'm creating a widget but the title and description is not translatable.

I'm often face this problem with arrays, I use `esc_html__()` inside the array which is supposed to return the translated string to the `$key` but for some reason it doesn't work, so I find myself using the `esc_html__()` outside the array, however how can I do that here:

```
function __construct() {
    $op = array(
        'name' => esc_html__( 'some title', 'my-plugin' ),
        'description' => esc_html__( 'some description goes here', 'my-plugin' )
    );
    parent::__construct( 'pk_members_widget', '', $op );
}
```

Most importantly, why it doesn't work when you add it in the array?
Thanks.

Comment: `esc_html_e()` and `_e()` wouldn't work but there's no reason what you've got there shouldn't work. At least in terms of those functions. You've got the name in the wrong place though. The widgets name goes in the 2nd argument of the constructor, not the options array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created simple widget to find out why you have such a problem. Everything is working fine. Below I give you my code as an example.

```
/**
 * Register widget
 */
function wpse_287570_register_widget()
{
    register_widget('WPSE_287570_Widget');
}

add_action('widgets_init', 'wpse_287570_register_widget');

/**
 * Create widget
 */
class WPSE_287570_Widget extends WP_Widget {

    public function __construct()
    {
         $op = array(
            'name' => esc_html__( 'some title', 'wpse_287570' ),
            'description' => esc_html__( 'some description goes here', 'wpse_287570' )
        );

        parent::__construct( 'wpse_287570_widget', '', $op );
    }
}


/**
 * Load the plugin translations
 */
function wpse_287570_load_textdomain() {

    load_plugin_textdomain( 'wpse_287570', false, basename( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages' );
}

add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'wpse_287570_load_textdomain' );
```

I keep my translations in `languages` directory in the main directory of my plugin. My translations files are named from textdomain and locale: `wpse_287570-pl_PL.po` and `wpse_287570-pl_PL.mo`.